# Asp.net Telerik Ajax

Tags: asp.net-ajax, telerik

Hi i am trying to get a master page into my web project. I have the Following code for my masterpage.

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CraigavonAquaitcs.master.cs" Inherits="Craigavon_Aquatics.CraigavonAquaitcs" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
   <link href="style1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    <title>Craigavon Aquatics</title>
    <telerik:RadStyleSheetManager id="RadStyleSheetManager1" runat="server" />
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder> 
    </head>
   <body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">

   <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

       <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server">
           <Scripts>
               <%--Needed for JavaScript IntelliSense in VS2010--%>
               <%--For VS2008 replace RadScriptManager with ScriptManager--%>
               <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.Core.js" />
               <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQuery.js" />
               <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQueryInclude.js" />
           </Scripts>
       </telerik:RadScriptManager>
       <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
       </telerik:RadAjaxManager>
       <div>
       </div>
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</form>  
</body>
</html>
```

When i am then trying to copy a rad menu from the toolbar i keep getting errors. I am wondering if what i am trying to do is possible. any answers greatly appricated

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I do not get what you mean by "trying to copy a rad menu from the toolbar". What errors do you get, where is the code for the menu? Btw, you may do a cross-post on the Telerik forums to get help from there.